# Cert-manager renewal time not showing correctly (incorrect duration)

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I am following the devops guy tutorial for setting up CERT manager.

Steps:

Create new kind cluster

```
kind create cluster --name certmanager --image kindest/node:v1.19.1
```

get cert-manager yaml

```
curl -LO https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.0.4/cert-manager.yaml
```

Install cert-manager

```
kubectl apply -f cert-manager-1.0.4.yaml
```

Test the certificate creation process

```
kubectl create ns cert-manager-test

kubectl apply -f ./selfsigned/issuer.yaml
```

I modified the cert to look like (add `duration` and `renewBefore`)

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: selfsigned-cert
  namespace: cert-manager-test
spec:
  duration: 1h 
  renewBefore: 20m
  dnsNames:
    - example.com
  secretName: selfsigned-cert-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: test-selfsigned
```

Apply cert

```
kubectl apply -f ./selfsigned/certificate.yaml
```

```
kubectl describe certificate selfsigned-cert
```

Show the following

```
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    example.com
  Duration:  1h0m0s
  Issuer Ref:
    Name:        test-selfsigned
  Renew Before:  20m0s
  Secret Name:   selfsigned-cert-tls
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-12-14T00:35:09Z
    Message:               Certificate is up to date and has not expired
    Reason:                Ready
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2022-03-14T00:35:09Z
  Not Before:              2021-12-14T00:35:09Z
  Renewal Time:            2022-03-14T00:15:09Z
  Revision:                1
```

Why is the renewal time 90 days from today? It should be 1 hour from the time I created it ~ (`2021-12-14T00:35:09Z`) as I set the `duration` to 1 hour!

EDIT: I actually updated to the latest cert-manager (v.1.6.1) and did the exact same steps. It seems to work. Maybe it was bug in that version. Weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted community wiki answer for better visibility based on the OP edit in the main question. Feel free to expand it.

---

The solution for the issue is to upgrade to the current, supported version (from the OP edit in main question):

> I actually updated to the latest cert-manager (v.1.6.1) and did the exact same steps. It seems to work. Maybe it was bug in that version. Weird!

Version 1.6.1 is [currently supported (as of today - 14.12.2021)](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/supported-releases/#supported-releases) until Feb 9, 2022.

Version 1.0.4 is [outdated, not supported since](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/supported-releases/#old-releases) Feb 10, 2021.

Comment: I tried with cert manger v1.9.0, but I am facing the same issue.